# Question involving two functions f and g

Tags: functions

f(x)= $\ x^2 $ , $\ x > 2 $ $$ $$ g(x)= $\ x^2 $ , x $ \in  $ [0,4]

Explain why f and g are different functions

Comment: $R_f=(4,+\infty)$ and $R_g=[0,16]$ and $D_f \ne D_g$

Comment: Each function has a different domain, hence each function has a different range.

Comment: @barakmanos Yes, the functions have a different range here, but that is (in contrast with different domain) not relevant. E.g. take $x\mapsto|x|$ on the distinct domains $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$. Distinct domains, hence distinct functions. But the ranges coincide.

Comment: @drhab: What I meant was $[\text{same operation}]\wedge[\text{different domain}]\implies[\text{different range}]$. But I agree that two functions are different if and only if any of these $3$ "attributes" is different.

Answer (score 3):

They are different because they are defined on different domains. One is defined for any $x$ that are greater than $2$, while the other is defined for $x$ between $0$ and $4$. For functions to be equal, they must first of all accept the same range of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Because two functions are equal if they have same formulation and same domain. f(x) and g(x) have first condition but their domains are different so they are different.

Comment: They don't need to have the same formulation, only the same value everywhere. The difference is subtle, but important. For instance, if $f$ and $g$ are defined for all real numbers as $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac xn)^n$ and $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$, then they are the same function.

Answer (score 1):

A function $h:D\to C$ is a subset of $D\times C$ such that for every $c\in D$ there is exactly one $y\in C$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in D\times C$. In this context:

- $D$ is its domain.
- $G:=\{\langle x,h(x)\rangle\mid x\in D\}$ is its graph.
- $C$ is its codomain.
- $R:=\{h(x)\mid x\in D\}$ is its range.

---

Commonly two functions $f,g$ are said to be equal if they have the same **domain** and secondly have the same **prescription**. These conditions are **necessary**. In the case mentioned in your question the prescription for both is $x\mapsto x^2$, so that condition is satisfied. However, the domains are not the same, so $f$ and $g$ are different functions.

Equivalently you can say that commonly two functions $f,g$ are equal if (again) they have the same domain and secondly the same **graph**.

Often these conditions are looked at as **sufficient** conditions, but not always. Next to domain and graph a function also has a **codomain**. For instance function $f$ mentioned in your question can be looked at as function having $(4,\infty)$ as codomain, but also as a function having sets like $\mathbb R$ of $[-1,\infty)$ as codomain. In fact any set $C$ that contains the **range** of $f$ - which is the set of possible outputs - can serve as a codomain of $f$. There are fields in mathematics where for $f=g$ it also is demanded that the codomains of $f$ and $g$ coincide.